# Nginx rewrite /path?params to /longer/path.html?params

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Simple one - but I would rather use location + rewrite vs if + rewrite (if is evil, correct?)

old url: /app?key=1234

new url: /system/app.html?key=1234

Tried

```
location  /app {
  rewrite ^/app$ /system/app.html break;
}
```

and only got a 404...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
location  /app {
  rewrite ^/app(.*)$ /system/app.html$1 permanent;
}
```